# Get mysql query when i dont need

Tags: php, mysql

I built a website that takes a random row from a MySQL table.

The values I am interested in are `Exercise` and `solution`.

When I check if the solution the user wrote is the same as the one I got from the database, a new query is running and replacing my solution.
the query:

```
$query="SELECT Exercise,solution FROM exercises WHERE rank = '".$Rank."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$Exercise=$row["Exercise"];
$Solution=$row["solution"];
```

checking the answer:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['postBTN']))
{
    if($_POST['solution'] == $Solution){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('yes');</script>";
        $progression = ($progression+1);
        $query="UPDATE users SET progression = '".$progression."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('no');</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

When I check the answer a new query is running and replacing the solution.

Comment: I'm still kind of vague about your question but I think you may be asking why you're data is being over written. The only thing can do that is the MySQL UPDATE query. If you have firebug, try to see if anything is being submitted twice from the XHR panel.

Comment: in my table there is id Exercise solution and rank,
the querty request random Exercise and solution by giving the rank.
for some reason i get a new querty before i check if the solution the user gave is the same as i got from the mysql

Comment: I suppose you have some other problem, because you can't update your table `exercises` from an update-query you're running on table `users`

Comment: Please don't use mysql functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or pdo. Other than that: the code snippets you posted should work fine, they can hardly be the cause of your overwriting issue. You should look elsewhere (or post more code)